# Qml Map item offset

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I'm designing a program to display the location of the car on the map as it moves live.

Everything works well,
Except for the car mark appears in the middle of the map.

[image: map1]

I want a car mark showing near the bottom of the map, to give a broad view of the map.

[image: map2]

After searching the official site, i found *pan()* and works well when placed inside a button.

But the problem is that I want to execute the *pan()* without pressing the button.

main.qml

```
property real x: ...
property real y: ...

Plugin {id: esri; name: "esri"}

Map {
    id: map
    plugin: esri
    center: QtPositioning.coordinate(x,y)
    onCenterChanged: map.pan(0,-10) // Error: The program has unexpectedly finished.
    ...

    MapQuickItem {
        coordinate: QtPositioning.coordinate(x,y)
        onCoordinateChanged: map.pan(0,-10) // Dose nothing
        ...
    }
}

Button {
    onClick: map.pan(0,-10) // Work good
}
```

How to execute the *pan()* automatically ? or Is there another way to offset mark of center?

Comment: What about `center: QtPositioning.coordinate(x,y-10)`?

Comment: It works only if the nose of the car is to the north, but if the nose of the car is in another direction, the map is moving in the same direction (for example, if the nose is to the east, the map is moves to the right instead of the bottom) (For example, if the nose of the south, the map is moves to the top rather than the bottom) (For example, if the nose is for the west, the map moves to the left instead of the bottom)

Comment: Is there a mathematical equation for change X and Y by rotation?

Comment: Taking the cos and sin of the angle.